# Compatibility of the latest Gothic 3 community patch

Tags: gothic-3

After installing the latest version of the Gothic 3 community patch (V1.74), will I be able to continue using savegames that have been made using earlier versions of the game (in my case v1.6) and just miss some of the improvements made by v1.74, or will I have to start a new game from the beginning?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to start a new game. Developer notes:

> Three years, 7 month and 18 days after the release of Gothic 3, the Community Patch Team released the definitly last version of the Community Patch for the game. Again this patch contains several improvements, which can be looked up in the change log.
>
> Savegames made with patch version 1.7x are compatible with the CP 1.74. Older savegames (1.60 or earlier) are not compatible. Please take a look at the download description for more information.